# Error in function. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, sequence, return-value, user-defined-functions

I wrote a function to create a domain to collect the intenisty of light which comes into a probe. When I use a single value for the starting point is fine, but when I set an array of poitns (because I need to describe a surface and the integrate the intensity onto this surface) it raises the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I tried to verify the shape of the different arrays and it (3,) and (3,), so in theory there is no inconsistence... Here the function

```
def probe_intensity(cone_FOV, n_circles):
    probeI = 0
    # probe location information
    #probe_angle = 5.0/4.0*np.pi
    #tvar=np.linspace(4.09,4.186,30)
    ray_cone_angle = cone_FOV/(2.0*n_circles)
   # T0 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
    r = 6.2
    x = 5.5
    probe_angle = np.linspace(1.2334*np.pi-1,1.2334*np.pi+1,30)
    probe_direction_angle = probe_angle - np.pi
    #R1=np.ones(len(probe_angle))
    # probe direction
    for k in probe_angle:

# getting the estimated cone for a single ray
#ray_cone_angle = cone_FOV/(2.0*n_circles)

# probe position information
#r = 6.2
#x = 5.5

        R0 = np.array([5.5,
               r*np.sin(probe_angle)+0.0001,
               r*np.cos(probe_angle)+0.0001])*0.001

        gamma = probe_direction_angle

        ROT1 = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0],
                  [0, np.cos(gamma), np.sin(gamma)],
                  [0, -np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma)]])


# vector T0 before any rotation
        T0 = np.array([0, 0, 1])

# vector T1 - probe axis vector
        T1 = np.array(ROT1*np.matrix(T0).T).flatten()

    # rotation for the cone_half_angle
        for ray_carrier_angle in [(i + 0.5)*ray_cone_angle for i in range(n_circles)]:

            alpha = ray_carrier_angle

            ROT2 = np.matrix([[np.cos(alpha), 0, np.sin(alpha)],
                          [0, 1, 0],
                          [-np.sin(alpha), 0, np.cos(alpha)]])

        # rotating to make a full circle of the cone
            for beta in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, int(np.round(n_circles*np.pi))):
                ROT3 = np.matrix([[np.cos(beta), np.sin(beta), 0],
                              [-np.sin(beta), np.cos(beta), 0],
                              [0, 0, 1]])

            # second rotaiton for the cone after the probe direction rotation
                T3 = np.array(ROT1*ROT3*ROT2*np.matrix(T0).T).flatten()
                print R0
                print R0.shape
                print T3
                print T3.shape
                T3=list(T3)
                R0=list(R0)


                ray_solution = ray_trace_solve_ivp(R0, T3, 0.0005)
                t, I = field.integrate_trace(ray_solution, 0.0005)
            #s,e,alpha,I = field.getspectra

        # Add the intensity of the ray to the intensity gathered at the probe. Dot product takes care of the projection
            probeI += I[-1]*np.dot(T0, T3)
            print probeI

return probeI
```

the other function which is called is

```
def ray_trace_solve_ivp(R0, T0, optical=False, dt=np.inf, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-2):
    y0 = np.r_[R0, T0]

    if optical:
        differential_equation = eikonalODE1system_optical
    else:
        differential_equation = eikonalODE1system_physical

    sol = solve_ivp(differential_equation, [0, 0.5], y0,
                    events=limit_functions,
                    dense_output=True,
                    max_step=dt,
                    atol=atol,
                    rtol=rtol)
    return sol
```

I get the following error message:

```
  File "/home/tont_fe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/tont_fe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/tont_fe/data/cfd/OH_analysis/OHstar_ray_tracing/oh_ray_trace_candidate_cone_federica.py", line 1109, in 
    print("probe intensity=", probe_intensity(np.pi/20.0, 10))

  File "/home/tont_fe/data/cfd/OH_analysis/OHstar_ray_tracing/oh_ray_trace_candidate_cone_federica.py", line 878, in probe_intensity
    ray_solution = ray_trace_solve_ivp(R0, T3, 0.0005)

  File "/home/tont_fe/data/cfd/OH_analysis/OHstar_ray_tracing/oh_ray_trace_candidate_cone_federica.py", line 690, in ray_trace_solve_ivp
    rtol=rtol)

  File "/home/tont_fe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py", line 456, in solve_ivp
    solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)

  File "/home/tont_fe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py", line 96, in __init__
    support_complex=True)

  File "/home/tont_fe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py", line 120, in __init__
    self._fun, self.y = check_arguments(fun, y0, support_complex)

  File "/home/tont_fe/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py", line 15, in check_arguments
    y0 = y0.astype(dtype, copy=False)
```

Comment: Fix the indents.  Show us (and yourself) exactly where the error occurs. Tell us about the variables at that point (type, shape,dtype, etc).  In other words all the useful stuff needed to debug such an error.

Comment: I think that the error occurs when calling the ray_solve_ivp function, where at the beginning I pack the two arrays in a single array, so when the np.r_(R0,T0) is called.  y0 = y0.astype(dtype, copy=False). Could maybe help specifying a dtype in y0? and if yes, which one?

Comment: The error message should show exactly which line has the problem!

Comment: I put the error messagee in the post!

Comment: Have you  checked your inputs to the `ivp` function agaist the documented requirements?  type, shape dtype etc?

Comment: From `ivp` docs: `y0,array_like, shape (n,)`.  Is that true for your `y0`.  Is it a 1d array (and same `n` as the function?  What `dtype`?  It should be numeric, float, int, etc.  You are the one who can insert a `print` statement in the `ray_trace_solve_ivp` to check this.

Comment: The print y0 in ray trace solve gives me two arrays, one for R0 and one for T0, but they don't look as 1D arrays, and it's quite obvious due to the fact that I make a cycle to create multiple points fot evaluating more than 1 radius. the shape of y0  is (6,). But I really don't understand what shpould I do to make it work :(

Comment: What does `y0.astype(float)` do?

Comment: I will try to see what happens, but the problem is that I am dealing with arrays. So the first element of R0 is a float, but the other two elements are arrays. Maybe if I manage to write a list if R0 made of single arrays, whis could help?

Comment: y0 = np.r_[R0, T0]
y0.astype(float)
print y0

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-457b7d437adb>", line 2, in <module>
    y0.astype(float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

So the relevant parts of your code are:

```
probe_angle = np.linspace(1.2334*np.pi-1,1.2334*np.pi+1,30)
R0 = np.array([5.5,
               r*np.sin(probe_angle)+0.0001,
               r*np.cos(probe_angle)+0.0001])*0.001
T0 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
y0 = np.r_[R0, T0]
```

Or simplified a bit:

```
In [96]: R0 = np.array([1, np.linspace(0,1,3), np.linspace(0,3,3)])             
In [97]: R0                                                                     
Out[97]: array([1, array([0. , 0.5, 1. ]), array([0. , 1.5, 3. ])], dtype=object)
In [98]: T0 = np.array([0,0,1])                                                 
In [99]: np.r_[R0,T0]                                                           
Out[99]: 
array([1, array([0. , 0.5, 1. ]), array([0. , 1.5, 3. ]), 0, 0, 1],
      dtype=object)
In [100]: _.astype(float)                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-b12cc607d111> in <module>
----> 1 _.astype(float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Your `R0`, and then `y0` constructor, makes an object dtype array - an array that contains arrays.

But `solve_ivp` requires a (n,) float array, where `n` is the number of values that `differential_equation` produces.

The immediate problem is in creating a numeric array from that `y0`.  Since I don't know what you need or want, I'm not going to propose an fix.

Also I don't know anything about the `differential_equation`.  I don't know how many value it returns.  Just one, three?  Or does it vary with size of the `y0` input?

Step back and work on a simpler problem.  Make sure you understand the requirements of `solve_ivp`, both the function and the `y0`.

And when you come back with new questions, please make it easier to help!

Comment: So the differential equations gives as output an array of 6 elements. I think I found a way to solve the error anyway. I just take each element of the array R0 (made of multiple arrays ) and I extract an array from this values. Essentially I separate the different arrays and put them in a list. What I want is essentially to have a cycle which produces a results for each pair of arrays R0 and T3. I would like to post here the solution I adopted, so you can tell me if it can be a useful workaround.

Comment: for k in probe_angle: 
        R0 = np.array([x,
               r*np.sin(probe_angle)+0.0001,
               r*np.cos(probe_angle)+0.0001])*0.001
        for i in range(0,len(probe_angle)):
            R_i=np.array([x,R0[1][i],R0[2][i]])
            Rlist.append(R_i)

Comment: T3 = np.array(ROT1*ROT3*ROT2*np.matrix(T0).T).flatten()
            print T3     
            for idx in range(0,len(probe_angle)):
                T3_idx=np.array([x,T3[1][idx],T3[2][idx]])
                T3list.append(T3_idx)
            for elem in Rlist:
                for item in T3list:
                    ray_solution = ray_trace_solve_ivp(elem, item, 0.0005)
                    t, I = field.integrate_trace(ray_solution, 0.0005)